# Excel protected sheet BeforeDoubleClick event

Tags: vba, excel

How to make working this code then sheet is protected? Target Cells are not protected (unchecked in properties)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("printR")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Cancel = True
        Target.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try including this somewhere in your code

`ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="123"`

then:

```
Sheets("sheetName").Protect Password:="123"
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this works in my workbook, but follow the link for some more examples of use, one of these might help -  http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=117:run-vba-macros-on-protected-worksheet-unprotect-a-protect-userinterfaceonly-argument-worksheetprotect-method&catid=79&Itemid=475

Comment: i cant unprotect sheet within my code only separatly

Comment: at the start of the code its worth unprotecting then performing your actions then protect again.